# Nested Fragment not respecting max width

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm trying to migrate to a *Single Activity Application* (and getting ready to use the new JetPack Navigation library).

I got a Flexible UI (typical dual pane fragment): Activity with size dependent layout and adding dynamically one or two fragments (as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui)). The main fragment contains the list of items, the secondary fragment contains the item details.

I want to translate the logic contained in the Activity to a Fragment and all is working fine but for some reason in the case of the wide layout (the one that allows to show the main fragment and the secondary fragment at the same time, in a tablet, for example) **the main fragment occupies  the entire width (it should be 50%)**. The secondary fragment works well (it can be seen below the main one).

[image: Bad layout]

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Activity layout:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    android:name="jp.rodriguez.kanjisenpai.fragment.StudyListManagePanelFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"/>
```

StudyListManagePanelFragment layout creation:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_studylistmanage, container, false)

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    // Make back button work properly in single pane version
    fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction().setPrimaryNavigationFragment(this).commit()

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        studyingFragment = StudyListManageFragment()
        childFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(studyingFragment)
                .add(R.id.mainFragment, studyingFragment)
                .commit()
    } else
        studyingFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mainFragment) as StudyListManageFragment
}

fun showStudyListDetails(studyList: StudyList) {
    if (view!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.fragmentDetails) != null) { // Dual pane
        val oldDetailsFragment = termsFragment

        val fragmentTransaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        if (oldDetailsFragment != null)
            fragmentTransaction.remove(oldDetailsFragment)

        if (studyList.itemCount != 0 || studyList.isUserCreated) {
            val detailsFragment = StudyListTermFragment()
            detailsFragment.studyListId = studyList.id
            fragmentTransaction
                    .add(R.id.fragmentDetails, detailsFragment, "termDetailsFragment")

        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

xlarge layout (I tried a lot of different layouts but it does not work, same code in Activity words):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5"
        tools:layout="@layout/list_item_studylist" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentDetails"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5"
        tools:ignore="InconsistentLayout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Both fragments are androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment.

Any ideas why the first FrameLayout always have maximum width (not 50%) when used with nested fragments?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
    tools:layout="@layout/list_item_studylist" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentDetails"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline"
    tools:ignore="InconsistentLayout" />
```

Comment: you could use this layout for your tablet, and for mobile you should have single frame layout. store your two frame layout's layout file in your layout-large directory. and handle them in activity as per device type.

Comment: Same result. Probably this layout works fine if used on an activity but not on a nested frame.